# Prove $P+G$ and $(P-1)!x-(G-2)$ are coprime

Tags: number-theory

I've been interested in studying twin primes--- not to try to prove the nearly unprovable twin primes conjecture, but just in and of themselves, with the hope that maybe I could find something that could lead to something that could lead to something... that could eventually help prove the twin primes conjecture.

I'm trying to show that where $P$ is the lesser of a twin prime pair, $G$ is an integer $>0$ and $x$ is an integer $>0$ that $P+G$ and $(P-1)!x-(G-2)$ are coprime.

This seems plausible based on this cursory glance using $P=11$:

$G$...$x$...$10!x-(G-2)$...coprime?

1...1...12...3628801...yes

2...1...13...3628800...yes

3...1...14...3628799...yes

4...1...15...3628798...yes

1...2...12...7257601...yes

2...2...13...7257600...yes

3...2...14...7257599...yes

4...2...14...7257598...yes

1...3...12...10886401...yes

2...3...13...10886400...yes

3...3...14...10886399...yes

4...3...15...10886398...yes

1...4...12...14515201...yes

2...4...13...14515200...yes

3...4...14...14515199...yes

4...4...15...14515198...yes

So I've tried looking at $a(P+G)+b[(P+1)!x-(G-2)]=1$ to try to find some values for $a$ and $b$ that work.  I find myself stymied there.

I've also tried proof by contradiction, by assuming $P+G$ and $[(P+1)!x-(G-2)$ have a common factor.  This gets me $(P+G)/j = [(P+1)!x-(G-2)]/k$ which gets me $k(P+G)-j[(P-1)!x-(G-2)]=0$.  I find myself similarly stymied trying to find values for $j$ and $k$ that create a contradiction.

So that's where I am.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For $(P,x,G)=(3,1,4)$, $P+G=7$ and $(P-1)!x-G+2=0$ are not coprime.

Answer (score 0):

$P=11, G=15, x=13$ then $P+G=26$ and $(P-1)!x-(G-2)=10!\times 13 - 13$ is divisible by $13$ and $P+G=26$ is divisible by 13.

Comment: We can say this, although trivial, if $x < P $ and $P < G$ twin primes then the two are coprime. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will not hold for any prime $P$ (lesser twin or not).

Let $Q$ be any prime $>P$, and let $G=P-Q$. Then $(P-1)!$ is coprime to $Q$. Therefore for some $x$ we have that $x(P-1)!+(G-2)$ is divisible by $Q$ also.

Answer (score 0):

We wish to prove if $p$ and $p+2$ are primes and $n,m$ are positive integers then:

$p+n$ and $(p-1)!m -n+2$ are coprime.

This is false, take an odd prime $q$ that is not a divisor of of $(p-1)!$ and $q>p+2$ . Take $n=q-p$ (so $p+n=q$ a multiple of $q$). Finally take $m$ so that $(p-1)!m\equiv(2-n)\bmod q$ (in other words the inverse of $((p-1)!m)^{-1}(n-2)$ which exists since this number is not a multiple of $q$, notice $n-2$ is not a multiple of $q$ since $2<n<q$). This makes both $p+n$ and $(p-1)!m-n+2$ multiples of $q$.

In other words we can always find a counterexample no matter which value we give to $p$.